# JWT Middleware name

Tags: php, laravel

In `app/kernel.php`, middleware only works if it's not `jwt.auth`.

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'jwt.auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\JwtMiddleware::class,
    ];
```

And the routes

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['jwt.auth']], function () {
    Route::get('user', 'UserController@getAuthenticatedUser');
});
```

If I name the middleware `jwt.aut` instead of `jwt.auth` it works.

I'm actually using [tymondesigns/jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) and I saw it has it's own middleware in `Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware`, but anyways I don't uderstand why it uses his middleware instead of mine.

This is what I have in `kernel.php`

```
protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            // \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            // \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            // \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];
```

Comment: Could you check protected $middlewareGroups  and protected $middleware in the Kernel file?

Comment: @ManuelEduardoRomero Updated. I have nothing I commented almost all of them because I don't need cookies and Sessions.

Comment: Could you check if you have jwt.php in /config folder? if not you need to run "php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider""

Comment: Yes I have already done that